# JS: Function call over-rides my other 2 function calls?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to design a menu system for upgrading attack skills. For example, when you click upgrade "strike skill", you get a circle with 3 subset skills to upgrade to.

[image: Upgrade System]

The Problem I am running into is my function calls. The last function of similar type, seems to over-ride the first 2 functions, so instead of filling all 3 circles in with their numbers, it instead just overwrites the last 2 instead. Why does it do this and how can I fix it?

The problem:

```
skills("skills", "attack1", "I");   
skills("skills", "attack2", "II");  
skills("skills", "attack3", "III");
```

Javascript Code:

```
 function upgradeBar() {
     menu("upgradeMenu", "systemMenu");
 }


 function menu(classID, id) {
        var button = dom.el("skill"); // Apply DIV to THIS location
        var x = document.createElement("div");
        x.setAttribute("class", classID);
        x.setAttribute("id", id);
        button.appendChild(x);

    function skills(classID, id, text){
        var circle = dom.el("systemMenu"); // Apply DIV to THIS location
        var x = document.createElement("div");
        x.setAttribute("class", classID);
        x.setAttribute("id", id);
        circle.appendChild(x);
        dom.setText("attack1", text);
        }
    skills("skills", "attack1", "I");   
    skills("skills", "attack2", "II");  
    skills("skills", "attack3", "III");  
}
```

CSS Code:

```
.upgradeMenu {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
}

#attack1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -10px;
}

#attack2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
#attack3 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 23px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean dom.setText(id, text); insetad of dom.setText("attack1", text); ?

Comment: I mean skills("skills", "attack1", "I"). Instead of putting 1, 2, 3 in all 3 circles, it only populates 1 circle because it overwrites the first 2 calls.

Comment: The last line of the function is `dom.setText("attack1", text);` so it writes the text to "attack1" every time.

Comment: Ah I feel like a idiot now. Thanks Juhana, I missed that completely :)